# How can I view LOGVV?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source, dalvik

Looking at the code for the Dalvik VM in the AOSP, and I see a bunch of logging calls with "LOGVV". How can I enable logcat to see this? Is it just "adb logcat *:VV"? Or, do I need to get the log from someplace else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires recompilation of the Dalvik VM.  It's enabled with the `VERY_VERBOSE_LOG` switch.  See [Common.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Common.h#65) for the implementation.

The switch makes `LOGVV` equivalent to `ALOGV`.  By default, `ALOGV` is not compiled in either, so you will need to define `LOG_NDEBUG 0` as well.

The log calls are intended for debugging the VM, so it's assumed that rebuilding the VM is easy for anyone who wants to enable them.